# How to remove the attribute element in the layout in magento 2

Tags: product, layout, magento2.3.1, remove

I wish to remove the attribute element in the catalog_product_view.xml file

I have tried below

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
<attribute name="itemtype" remove="true"/>
<attribute name="itemscope" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

But throws error.

When I added remove='true' to these attributes - I got the following error:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'attribute', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
```

Answer (score 8):

I have solved the problem by following link https://github.com/outeredge/magento-structured-data-module/commit/41ea6ca81a2d8499b954498bce09b7be9d80dc2a

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
<attribute name="itemtype" value=""/>
<attribute name="itemscope" value=""/>
</body>
</page>
```